# How to find the Id of model corresponding to clicked item?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

How to know the Id of item I clicked? my code is given below:

```js
$(function() {
  ipl.mvc.view.openings_view = ipl.mvc.view.view_base.extend({
    template: '/assets/t/plmt/companies.tmpl.html',
    ID: '#tmpl_openings',
    events: {
      "click #edit": "editpost"
    },
    initialize: function() {
      var _this = this;
      _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll', 'render', 'editpost');
      _this.loadTemplate(_this.template, function() {
        _this.model = new ipl.mvc.model.companies_model([]);
        _this.model.view = _this;
        _this.model.bind('change', _this.render, _this);

      });
    }

    ,
    render: function() {
      var _this = this
      jsonData = _this.model.toJSON();
      _.each(jsonData, function(model) {
        $(_this.ID).tmpl(model).appendTo(_this.el);
        return _this;
      });
    }
    ,
    editpost: function(e) {
      console.log("EDIT CLICKED");
      e.preventDefault();
      var ele = $(e.target);
      console.log(ele);
      _this.model = new ipl.mvc.collection.companies_collection([]);
      var id = _this.model.get("id");
      alert(id);
    }
  });
});
```

and template

```
<a href="!/editpost/${id}" data-id="${id}"><button id="edit"  ><img   src="/assets/img/pencil.png" /></button></a>
```

I need id to use in edit function, but not getting `${id}` from template, and I follow those steps and I didn't get it? how to get the `${id}` of clicked item from template?

Comment: please take a look at the code you posted, i believe it's incorrect if you ask me it has too many closing brackets. try to reformat your code so that it looks more inviting to others to try and find a solution please

Answer (score 13, accepted):

actually what you need is this:

1. you have set the data-id on the html element in the template
2. you added a method to be executed on the right event (editPost)
3. in that editPost method you can do this:

   ```
   editPost: function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var id = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");
     var item = this.collection.get(id);
   }
   ```

**remark** i noticed your code has too many closing tags, so it won't run here,
and i also noticed in your editPost you try  _this but you never declare _this.
you should have had `var _this = this;` in that method.

**remark 2** i don't understand why you even need a data-id in this example,
there are two ways of rendering a view, either the view has a collection bound to it, or it has a model. When binding a collection to a view, you might somehow need to get the correct id from the element clicked to find the right model in your collection

but on your example, your view has a model bound to it, so you only have that 1 ID, which you can just get by calling `this.model.get('id');` i believe your entire code example from above, is copied from another example where they use a collection in the view, since both your rendering, and the use of the data-id property suggests this.

Answer (score -1):

This is another (newer versions of backbone?) way of doing this: (I see @Sander shows the `model.get` method in his remarks)

```
var AppointmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click' : 'alertTitle'
  },

  alertTitle : function(e) {
    // this.model.get('id') is what you're looking for
    alert( this.model.get('title') );
  }
});
```