# Problems obtaining id from a HTML element inside a view

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to do a a Backbone calendar application. I have a model `Event`, an `EventView` and a `DailyView`.

The `DailyView` loads a template which contains a table with a list of cells that represents the hour (e.g.:`td #09`). I want to click the cell and obtain its `id`, but when I do, I fail. I think I'm referencing the `el: div` from `DailyView` instead of the `td`.

```
DailyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    template: _.template($('#daily-view').html()),

    events: {
        'click td': 'onClick'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

        return this;
    },
    onClick: function(){
        var hour= $(this.el).attr("id");
        //This doesn't work
    }
```

I've thought of adding the cells as sub-views (sometimes empty, sometimes containing an `Event`), but I don't like this approach and I'd prefer not to add more elemtns to the DOM unless it's strictly necessary.

Is there a way I can reference the `td` instead of the `div`?

Comment: First, the tagName property identifies the type of element you want your view to represent. So you'll need it to be 'td', not 'div'. Second, for your td to be part of a table, you'll have to add it to a table yourself. That means you'll need to add it to the table markup yourself.

Comment: There's no need to `$(this.el)` when you already have [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el). And there's no need for that `_.bindAll` if you're going to supply the third argument to the `this.model.bind()` call anyway.

Comment: @kinakuta No, the `div` is correct in that context. `DailyView` is the wrapper that contains the table (and the cells). `EventView` represents individual elements. The problem wasn't related to representing the table.

@muistooshort Thanks, you are right. It's my first application with javascript (and jQuery and Backbone) and I need to clarify many concepts.

Comment: @AnimusNecandi ah, I see - I mis-interpreted what you were trying to do. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this post: [How to find the Id of model corresponding to clicked item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563663/how-to-id-of-item-did-i-click)

```
onClick: function(e){
    var hour = e.currentTarget.id;
    //This does work ?
}
```

Comment: It does!  I guess I didn't search properly. I don't have enough reputation to upvote you, since I just made my account, but you just convinced me of the utility of participating in this site. Thank you very much :P